# Unable to find class exception when applying UDFs in Hive On Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to switch the engine from `mr` to `spark` in Hive. For SQLs without UDFs all work fine, but when it comes to any SQL with UDF in it:

```
set hive.execution.engine=spark;
add jar viewfs:///path_to_the_jar/aaa.jar;
create temporary function func_name AS 'com.abc.ClassName';

select func_name(col_a) from table_name limit 100;
```

it always throw Exception as below in spark-cluster mode (in spark-client mode it's working fine).

```
ERROR : Job failed with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.abc.ClassName
org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find class: com.abc.ClassName
Serialization trace:
genericUDF (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.ExprNodeGenericFuncDesc)
colList (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.SelectDesc)
conf (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorSelectOperator)
childOperators (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorFilterOperator)
childOperators (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator)
aliasToWork (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.MapWork)
left (org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.ImmutablePair)
edgeProperties (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.SparkWork)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:156)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:133)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:670)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readClass(SerializationUtilities.java:181)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:118)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readClassAndObject(SerializationUtilities.java:176)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:40)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:708)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:214)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:708)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:214)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readClassAndObject(SerializationUtilities.java:176)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:40)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:708)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:214)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readClassAndObject(SerializationUtilities.java:176)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:40)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:708)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:214)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readClassAndObject(SerializationUtilities.java:176)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:161)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:39)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:708)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:214)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:708)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:214)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readClassAndObject(SerializationUtilities.java:176)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:153)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:39)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:708)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:214)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:686)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.KryoSerializer.deserialize(KryoSerializer.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.RemoteHiveSparkClient$JobStatusJob.call(RemoteHiveSparkClient.java:329)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver$JobWrapper.call(RemoteDriver.java:358)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver$JobWrapper.call(RemoteDriver.java:323)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.abc.ClassName
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:154)
    ... 63 more
```

Hive: 0.23

Spark: 2.0.3

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a bug in hive-0.23 for not supporting viewfs scheme. It's summed up as below:

http://jason4zhu.blogspot.hk/2018/04/hive-on-spark-unable-to-find-class.html